# Rails: How to get all parameters from url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Usually, we use like:

```
 params[:a] #to get a specific parameter's value
```

But how to get all the parameters the way we do in PHP?

```
  $_GET or $_POST
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You may simply use `params` as a Hash of all passed parameters (both GET and POST).

For example:

```
params.each do |key,value|
  Rails.logger.warn "Param #{key}: #{value}"
end
```

Update: Note, what `params` include parameters of categories:

- Path parameters (bound in routes)
- Query parameters (GET)
- Request parameters (POST)

If you want to access parameters of certain category only you may use:

```
request.path_parameters

request.query_parameters # or
request.GET

request.request_parameters # or
request.POST
```

All methods return [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), so you may access them by string or symbol key.

Comment: a=11
b=22
c=33
controller=alipay
action=return_url_process
it seems has some extra k-v