# Does Ruby on Rails have a standard mechanism of adding a param to current URL and removing one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

That is, if the current URL of the page is

```
http://www.foo.com/products/?q=fruit&order=ascending
```

then a way to link to a URL without the `order` param, and a way to link to a URL with an added param, such as `page=2`

(note that we can't just append `&page=2` to it, because what if the current URL has no `?`, then adding the `&` like that won't work)

Answer (score 0):

I think reconstructing the link would be a possible solution.

For example in your controller: `redirect_to products_path(:q => params[:q], :page => 2)`
Or in your view: `link_to products_path(:q => params[:q], :page => 2)`

It will redirect to `http://www.foo.com/products?q=fruit&page=2`

Comment: hm... the thing is I don't know in advance what params are on the URL, so the code above won't work when the URL has more params as the site develops

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352839/how-to-rails-get-all-parameters-from-url
Shows how to get all params from the url.

Comment: So the solution is still quite basic... no "one method doing the whole job" completely