# get url params or strip fullpath with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to save url params upon creation. I have `<%= f.hidden_field :registration_source, :value => request.fullpath %>` which saves 'merchant/register?source=cferfrefr4g'

however I'm only interested by params. How can I just get the params or trim everything before first question mark through a method?

Thanks

Comment: I removed the "regex" tag.  This is not a regex problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352839/how-to-rails-get-all-parameters-from-url

Answer (score 0):

You can get special parameters through `params`:

`<%= f.hidden_field :registration_source, :value => params[:source]`

Comment: Thx but how do I define source to retrieve url params only?

Comment: you need only `merchant/register`?

Comment: `<% params.each do |k, v|  %>
 <%= "?" + k.to_s + "=" + v if k == "source"%>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

try `<%= f.hidden_field :registration_source, :value => request.request_parameters %>` instead and you should just get the params in the value attribute.