# How to keep the query params when changing locale in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am trying to preserve query params when changing locale in Rails 6, I only found the `default_url_options` method & if I try to pass the params to that it doesn't work throwing unpermitted params passed exception

**For example:**

A URL having `http://localhost:3000/some_path?token=ABcasdjlaweQWd`

Should be changed to `http://localhost:3000/de/some_path?token=ABcasdjlaweQWd`

But currently, it only becomes: `http://localhost:3000/some_path` & I lose the query params

Keeping things secure is important, so I don't want to hack my way disabling the params filter, but it should be possible to pass the params during language change without big hacks.

**Update:**

I am changing local by navbar link_to btn (for different locale), for example: `link_to url_for( :locale => 'fr' )` that will change locale part of the current url to the french locale for example

*What is the correct way to maintain the query params on language change?*

Comment: It depends on how you're changing locale - is there a button on your site that acts as a link to a controller?

Comment: I should have explained this, thanks, I updated the question

Comment: @Mark, thank you, your comment lit up the way, only changing the language change button helped without too much changes

Comment: Happy you got there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without overriding the `default_url_options`, a better way is to make the language change button behave differently, so that it won't remove the query params

So instead of this:

```
= link_to url_for( locale: 'en' )
```

It should be changed to this, which will keep the params:

```
 = link_to request.params.merge( locale: 'en' )
```

Comment: Using `request.params` will include ALL params NOT just the query params. In other words, if you render a view after a POST request (instead of redirecting to another page) then the form params will be in the link as well. To solve this problem you should instead use `request.query_parameters.merge(locale: 'en')` (or `request.GET.merge(locale: 'en')`). All credits to that other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352860/123016